# How to fix my extremely slow copy paste Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA/macros and trying to figure out how to improve the speed of running a simulation. My code includes copying a date from one cell in a sheet, pasting it in another sheet and looping through this multiple times. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Run_Sim()

' Run_Sim Macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("Runs").Select
Range("A2:C100005").ClearContents

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 5001
    ' Calculate
    Sheets("Calc").Select
    Range("O3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Runs").Select
    Cells(i, 2).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then
        ' Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = vbRed
     '   Sheets("Calc").Select
     '   Range("O3").Select
     '   Selection.Copy
     '   Sheets("Runs").Select
     '   Cells(i, 2).Select
     '   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     '       :=False, Transpose:=False
    'End If
    Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
    Else
        Cells(i, 3).Value = 1
    End If
    Calculate
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Would ideally like to increase the number of simulations but the time it takes to get through this is a big limiting factor.

Comment: Do you always need to go to row 5001 or do you just need to go to the last used row? If so, what column is a good indicator of the last row

Comment: No, just need to go to the last used row. Column B would be a good indicator.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to speed, I see three major issues with your code

1. Do not use `.Select`
2. Use a value transfer (`Range.Value = Range.Value`) instead of `Copy/Paste`
3. Limit the scope of your code to the relevant ranges. Why loop 5,001 rows if you are only using 1,000 rows?

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Run_Sim()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Runs")
Dim cs As Worksheet: Set cs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc")
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ws.Range("A2:C" & LR).ClearContents
    For i = 2 To LR

        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = cs.Range("O3").Value
        ws.Range("A" & i) = i - 1

        If ws.Range("B" & i) = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i) = 0
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i) = 1
        End If

    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Also, since you are setting every row in `Column B` equal to one value, you can do that outside of the loop in one quick line. Notice the subtle difference between the above and below code. The operations inside the loop have been reduced which should lead to improved efficiency.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Run_Sim()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Runs")
Dim cs As Worksheet: Set cs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc")
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, CalcDate As Date

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ws.Range("A2:C" & LR).ClearContents
  ws.Range("B2:B" & i) = CalcDate '<-- Date transfer all at once

    For i = 2 To LR

        If ws.Range("B" & i) = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i) = 0
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i) = 1
        End If

    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Another option that I will not demonstrate here is to loop through a range (`For Each Cell in Range`) instead of using a variable range (`For i = 2 to LR`). These loops tend to be faster.

Comment: How would you suggest revising my code if I did need to go to 5001? The output I'm aiming for is a numbered table, numbered sequentially in column A with the value from "Calc" pasted into column B.

Comment: This code will go down to the last used row in column B

Comment: The code is dynamical determined by column B. If the column has 10 filled rows, it will run down 10 rows. If you have 5000 rows, it will run down 5000 rows. If you have x rows, it will run down x rows. It will be easier for you to test this prob